# Command work in terminal, but not in rails console with %w(cmd) or `cmd`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running `wkhtmltoimage`. I tried installing the `wkhtmltoimage-binary` gem, which caused a bunch of issues, and stopped the lib from working via ruby console, OR the shell. Once I removed the gem the command worked in the terminal. `wkhtmltoimage --quality 100 input.html output.jpg`, however once I open the Rails console and run it inside `cmd`, or `%w(cmd)`, I get this error:

```
rubygems_integration.rb:462:in `block in replace_bin_path': 
can't find executable wkhtmltoimage for gem wkhtmltoimage-binary. 
wkhtmltoimage-binary is not currently included in the bundle, 
perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile? (Gem::Exception)
```

Why does it check for the gem? Why not just run it? How can I work around this?

Comment: in console `%w(pwd)` returns `["pwd"]` and ``pwn`` -> `/Users/../project located`

Comment: So is the `wkhtmltoimage-binary` gem installed? If not, what error do you get when you try to install it?

Comment: @spickermann No, I removed the gem, as it was causing a `libjpeg8` error, even though that lib was installed. I removed the gem, but I still have wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltoimage libs installed (just not via the gem)

Comment: You probably mean `%x[...]` as `%w[...]` is an array of strings.

Comment: You need to install the `wkhtmltoimage-binary` gem or it won't work, as the error message says. Skipping that step isn't going to make it magically start working, you need to fix your gem installation issue first. It could be you have a binary in a place where your system gems can find it, but your bundle installed gems can't.

Comment: @tadman I don't undertstand, why do I need the gem? I have the lib installed on my computer, and it works when run in the terminal. All I want to do in ruby is trigger the code to run in the terminal. If I want to run `mv` or `pwd` via Ruby I don't need a `mv` or `pwd` gem, so why do I need one here?

Comment: Either you have to have `wkhtmltoimage` in the path where that gem expects it or you need that other gem. As a note `wkhtmltopdf` is an absolute nightmare to use in practice because it depends on this quirky custom WebKit binary, so if you're not too committed to it as of yet, you may want to cut and run. Tools like [Prawn](https://github.com/prawnpdf) and [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com) are a lot less fuss.

Comment: @tadman I'm still not understanding why I need to deal with the gem at all. I'm not running wkhtmltoimage in ruby. I want to run it like any other program directly in the terminal. I can run a imagemagick command in the shell without needing the rmagick gem, so why can't I do the same with wkhtmltoimage?

Comment: Find out where your `wkhtmltoimage` binary is then and run it with the full path.

Comment: can you please post the code that executes the system command?